# updating value of drop down list after clear them

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have 2 dropdown list with sql value that have initial value too that second drop down list changes after selecting from first drop down list so I should clear second drop down list value after changes happen in fist one but after clearing first drop down list my intial value doesn't appear what should I do in my behind code to show my initial value after clearing?

first dropdown:

```
<asp:dropdown ID="OrderNo" runat="server"   MaxLength="0" style="display: inline;" 
AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="OrderNo_SqlDS" DataTextField="OrderNo" 
DataValueField="OrderNo" onselectedindexchanged=" OrderNo_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
<asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Value="" /></asp:dropdown>
```

Second dropdown:

```
<asp:dropdown ID="Part" runat="server"   MaxLength="0" style="display: inline;" 
AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="Part_SqlDS" DataTextField="Part" 
DataValueField="Part" onselectedindexchanged=" Part_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
<asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Value="" /></asp:dropdown>
```

and in my behind code:

```
 protected void OrderNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Part.Items.Clear();
        Part.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An item is always selected in the DropDownList control. you should not clear the elements from the drop down list on selected index changed method. Try setting the data source property, before you do databind

```
    protected void OrderNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Part.DataSourceID="Part_SqlDS"
    Part.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: It does'nt change becouse without clearing it shows me all last values

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to use `OrderNo_SelectedIndexChanged` to bind the second control because the first dropdownlist causes postback. `Once postback happens SqlDataSource controls automatically refreshes and bind` data to databound controls.
2. `Your initial value disappears` because you cleared all items, and told the control to get data back (DataBind()). `What happens is` the control will only obtain the data from SqlDataSource and not from other source. Your initial value is gone unless you add it again this time using code behind. **`But the solution is`: `you don't need to clear items at all`**. I think you were afraid of duplicate items but that is not gonna happen with SqlDataSource control, it refreshes the data and if changes made to the source only the change appears.
3. `If you insist in using the code` use only part.DataBind(); you don't need to clear items. **Note**: In this case `you're causing double operation` because the DataSource control will bind your controls anyway.

Hope this helps !